# Terminal : bash: emulate: command not found

Tags: command-line, executable

I'm trying to fix the issue that executables downloaded by snap are not being added to the apps list or desktop. So I tried typing in

```
emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'
```

Though, it gave me this error:

```
bash: emulate: command not found
```

btw I have zsh installed

So what can I do ?

Comment: I guess you have to switch to zsh : `$ zsh` ..... and then `$ emulate ....`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks !! it worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing "zsh" does not mean this is your default shell.

You are getting this error probably because you are running bash.
What is the output of the $SHELL environment variable? Use the echo buitin command.

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

**Additional update** from comments below (credits due):

The environmental variable $SHELL is set upon login and stays the same even a shell change within your session. There is another command you can invoke to determine your current shell.

```
readlink /proc/$$/exe
```

While next command gives you the installed shells on your system.

```
$ cat /etc/shells

/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/git-shell
```

If you like to set your default shell to zch you'll have to find out where it's at:

```
$ type -a zsh   or which zsh
```

Then you can set your shell accordingly.

```
$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Comment: Note that `$SHELL` does not contain the shell you're currently running (the variable does not change if you launch zsh or any other shell) -- it contains your login shell.

Comment: `readlink /proc/$$/exe` will probably be a better choice